# Reading a CSV and Writing to Parquet in Azure Data Lake using Polars in Rust

Tags: rust, azure-storage, rust-polars

I am trying to read a CSV file from Azure Data Lake and subsequently write it as a Parquet file back into Azure Data Lake using the polars library in Rust. On Polars website, it claims to support reading and writing to all common files and cloud storages, including Azure Storage:

> Polars supports reading and writing to all common files (e.g. csv, json, parquet), cloud storage (S3, Azure Blob, BigQuery) and databases (e.g. postgres, mysql).

However, there are very limited examples available and all are related to AWS, and I am unable to find one that reads a CSV; instead, they are reading Parquet files.

I have also attempted to write a parquet file to the Azure Storage but with this uri `abfss://data@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/output/bronze/customers.parquet` but I get this error:
`thread 'main' panicked at 'called` Result::unwrap()`on an`Err `value: ComputeError(ErrString("unknown url scheme"))'`

```rust
use clap::Parser;

use cloud::AzureConfigKey;
use polars::prelude::*;

/*
How to run:
cargo run -- --input abfss://data@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/customers.csv --output abfss://data@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/output/bronze/customers.parquet
*/

/// Simple program to convet CSV to Parquet
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    /// Input file path
    #[arg(short, long, value_name = "INPUT-PATH")]
    input: String,

    /// Output file path
    #[arg(short, long, value_name = "OUTPUT-PATH")]
    output: String,
}

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {

    dotenvy::dotenv().unwrap();

    let args = Args::parse();

    let input_path = args.input;
    let output_path = args.output;

    let account_name = dotenvy::var("ACCOUNT_NAME").unwrap();
    let access_key = dotenvy::var("ACCESS_KEY").unwrap();
    let sas_key = dotenvy::var("SAS_KEY").unwrap();

    // Propagate the credentials and other cloud options.
    let cloud_options = cloud::CloudOptions::default().with_azure([
        (AzureConfigKey::AccountName, account_name.to_string()),
        (AzureConfigKey::AccessKey, access_key.to_string()),
        (AzureConfigKey::ContainerName, "data".to_string()),
        (AzureConfigKey::SasKey, sas_key.to_string())
        ]);

    let mut schema = Schema::new();
    schema.with_column("CustomerID".to_string().into(), DataType::Int64);
    schema.with_column("FirstName".to_string().into(), DataType::Utf8);
    schema.with_column("LastName".to_string().into(), DataType::Utf8);
    schema.with_column("FullName".to_string().into(), DataType::Utf8);
    
    // FIXME: There was no documention about how to read csv from cloud
    let df_csv = CsvReader::from_path(input_path)?
    .has_header(true)
    .with_dtypes(Some(Arc::new(schema)))
    .with_encoding(CsvEncoding::LossyUtf8)
    .finish()?;

    println!("{}", df_csv);

    let cloud_options = Some(cloud_options);
    
    // FIXME: This function returns an error that unknown url scheme 
    df_csv.lazy()
        .sink_parquet_cloud(
            output_path,
            cloud_options,
            Default::default(),
        )
        .unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

```ini
[package]
name = "poolstar"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
dotenvy = "0.15.7"
chrono = "0.4.31"
clap = { version = "4.4.4" , features = ["derive"] }
polars = { version = "0.33.2", features = ["lazy", "temporal", "describe", "json", "parquet", "dtype-datetime", "polars-io", "cloud", "azure", "cloud_write"] }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, is by using the [object_store](https://docs.rs/object_store/latest/object_store/) crate

```
use object_store::azure::MicrosoftAzureBuilder;
use object_store::path::Path;
use object_store::ObjectStore;
use polars::io::csv::CsvReader;
use polars::prelude::*;

const STORAGE_ACCOUNT: &str = "examplestorageaccount";
const CONTAINER_NAME: &str = "examplecontainer";
const INPUT_LOCATION: &str = "input.csv";
const OUTPUT_LOCATION: &str = "output.parquet";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), PolarsError> {
    let object_store = MicrosoftAzureBuilder::new()
        .with_account(STORAGE_ACCOUNT)
        .with_container_name(CONTAINER_NAME)
        .with_use_azure_cli(true)
        .build()?;

    let data = object_store.get(&Path::from(INPUT_LOCATION)).await?;

    let mut df = CsvReader::new(std::io::Cursor::new(data.bytes().await?))
        .infer_schema(Some(100))
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()?;

    println!("{:?}", df);

    let mut buffer = vec![];
    ParquetWriter::new(&mut buffer).finish(&mut df)?;

    object_store
        .put(&Path::from(OUTPUT_LOCATION), buffer.into())
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This snippet creates an `object_store` and fetches credentials using the Azure CLI. You can find other authentication options in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/object_store/latest/object_store/azure/struct.MicrosoftAzureBuilder.html).  It fetches the bytes of the remote csv file, and converts it to a Polars DataFrame.

In the last part, the DataFrame is written as parquet to a buffer, which is then written to the storage account.